# MySQL add a string as the default

Tags: mysql

I have a MySql Dbase with a members table - a particular field is say title - can I set a defaut for the field when a new record is created for instance can I have "to be validated" into the field when a new record is added - I did search the site but could not find the answer

Regards

John Berman

Comment: You could do that with a `TRIGGER`, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: thanks, any chance of an example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
ALTER TABLE members
ALTER COLUMN title SET DEFAULT 'to be validated'
```

Answer (score 1):

when you create your table, you just have to specify the default like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`new_table` (
  `pk` INT NOT NULL,
  `field` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT 'to be validated',
  PRIMARY KEY (`pk`));
```

Then, every time a new record is created it will default to that value if nothing else is passed.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a default value in the `create table` statement.  For instance:

```
title varchar(255) not null default 'title'
```

Or you can modify the column:

```
alter table table modify title varchar(255) default 'title'
```

You can set existing values in rows with `NULL` values using:

```
update table t
    set title = 'title'
    where title is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is correct. But you can use a simple tinyint or boolean field to indicate whether you have validated the field with a default value of false or 0. This saves a lot of space

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ....
    validated TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
```

After validating, you can change validated to 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a [TRIGGER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html), here an example

```
CREATE TABLE example6 (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(50)
);


CREATE TRIGGER to_be_validated BEFORE INSERT ON example6
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.title = CONCAT(NEW.title, ' (to be validated)');

INSERT INTO example6 (title) VALUES ('This is a test');

SELECT * FROM example6;
```

Result:

```
id | title
-------------------------------------
 1 | This is a test (to be validated)
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ceebf5/1)**

Comment: Somewhat overwhelmed by the responses now (what a great forum) so think I need to be more specific. I have a table called skypemembers - users sign up online and hence create a record. in the table I have 2 fields 1 - status and I want to add the phrase "not validated", 2 - membertype and i want to add the phrase"to be confirmed" - I can confirm the fields are empty to start with - readying the responses it looks like a trigger will do the job ? thanks in advance

Comment: @JohnBerman The other answers are what you want if I misunderstood your intention.